# Objective-C method name alias

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a fairly simple question which I cannot seem to find a definitive answer to.

Is there a way to make an alias name for a method **without** doing something like this:

```
- (void)method1
{ //Stuff }
- (void)method2
{ [self method1];}
```

I want `[self method2];` to equate to `[self method1];` by creating an alias. Is this possible in Objective-C?

Comment: I don't know of a way to accomplish this in Objective-C. What are you looking to gain through this behavior?

Comment: This looks a lot like an X-Y problem. Could you describe the core issue that you would like to address by avoiding to create a new method that performs forwarding?

Comment: This is simply for code readability. I have a few different sets of objects that I will be storing in one NSArray property and I want to be able to call a method from two different names simply so the code is human-readable. Of course this is not a necessity, but it would help if someone were trying to follow my code.

Comment: You could `#define method2 method1` and let the preprocessor handle it.

Comment: Be *very* careful with the preprocessor macro because it's pure textual substitution with very little context awareness. All references to the name of `method2` as a token will be replaced with the name of `method1`, whether used with your class or not, as a message selector or not, and that can have unanticipated side effects.

Comment: @David This smells like bad design;  if you own the implementations of the two classes and they work so much alike that you want to alias the methods, then rename the methods and be done with it.  If the classes are coming from libraries, then consider creating a wrapper object that normalizes the behavior as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to do this without writing much code, you're out of luck. As a rule of thumb, Obj-C doesn't have much "syntax sugar" and this is one of those situations.

Most of the time, you would just do exactly what you're trying to avoid. It's easy and it works.

But when that's not good enough, the Obj-C runtime has a feature called "Message Forwarding".

Basically, if your object receives a message (method invocation) that it doesn't know anything about, the default behaviour is to throw an exception. But your object can choose to do something else with it and there are millions of places where the Obj-C framework classes do so.

Most of the time you "forward" the message to another object, but you can do anything you want:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if (/* some check */) {
        /* do something */
        return;
    }

    // perform the superclass's implementation (which is probably to throw a "method not recognized" exception.
    [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
}
```

The official documentation with many more details can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html

Comment: Could you give some examples of where the Objective-C framework classes use this, or could potentially be using this?

Comment: @Scott The frameworks don't use this mechanism outside of the most esoteric circumstances.   Such patterns are to be avoided because they are fragile, confusing, and indicate that the underlying design is flawed and should be revisited.

Comment: @bbum I thought this is how class clusters are typically implemented? What do they do differently?

Comment: Class clusters create a new instance of a different class during `init`, there is no message forwarding.

Comment: @Wain and what about `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: I suppose `class_addMethod()` could work... I agree these things should be avoided, part of the reason I'm asking what Apple is doing is because I've never needed to do anything like this (in all my 10 years of Obj-C coding). I just assumed `forwardInvocation:` was how Apple did it.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert `NSManagedObject` does not use forwarding;  it dynamically creates method implementations for the modeled properties.  It is a very specific use case and solution that would not map well to general purpose use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok using a dynamic solution, you could use the objc runtime for this. `class_addMethod` is an API that would do this for you.

`class_addMethod` will not replace, but other APIs can - Be careful not to replace existing implementations. A good prefix for your selector's name would be a good idea, so that you can avoid collisions.